# Error on setting up my first profile in civiCRM 5.52 on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, profile

I thought I had done all the steps correctly but hit "Save" and got this:

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Cannot determine api action for CRM_UF_Form_Group.CRM_Core_Action "NO DESCRIPTION SET" not recognized.

No idea what to do next.

Comment: If you were putting in a redirect when the profile is created, use the full URL. I used a relative URL and got this error.